# How do I upgrade the python pip in Blender 3.3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the new Dream Textures addon in Blender 3.3 but I can't get past one of the steps because Blender requires that I upgrade the pip version from 21.2.4 to 22.2.2. I tried following the steps it gave me but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Did you see this bit in the readme?: 
    "Note for Windows users - If you get an error when installing dependencies that looks similar to the one described here, your dependency file paths might be too long (can't be longer than 256 characters). You can solve it by telling Windows to allow long file paths in the registry:
        Open up the Window registry (Start > Run > regedit)
        Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
        Set LongPathsEnabled to 1"

Comment: I got it working.
Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Could you maybe tell us what did it so it can help others like me with the same issue? Thanks.